# Gremlin3 avoiding terminate on empty relationships

Tags: gremlin

I'm having difficulty with possible empty relationships in gremlin3.

If I apply a filter on step (hasLabel) and the tranverser contains at least one label, everything runs fine. If not, transverse stops.

If I use optional, my condition gets ignored.

This is my query. The problem is on .hasLabel (within ($ {included})). I can get to work if I remove them.

```
result = await this.repository`g.V (${organization_uuid}).out()
                              .until(filter{{it.get().value("name")
                              .contains(${concept_name})}))
                              .repeat(inE().otherV().simplePath().timeLimit 
                              (100)).dedup().as('target')
                              .bothE().as('relation').otherV()
                              .hasLabel(within(${included}))
                              .as('descendant').union(select('target', 
                              'relation', 'descendant')
                              .by(valueMap(true)),outE('related').as 
                              ('direct').otherV().as('other')
                              .select ('direct','other').by(valueMap(true))) `;
```